# Can I connect to Windows 7 Remote Desktop with Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, remote-desktop, activex

I'd lilke to connect to my home Windows 7 Pro x64 PC from work. The only tool I have to do this with is Firefox.

I've tried running TSWeb on IIS for the RDP session but I can't connect.

I think it's due to Active X control requirements.

Can I access RDP through firefox at all?

UPDATE: Probably worth mentioning, the motivation for not using Logmein or similar is that their web pages are blocked by the office proxy. I'd like to host a webpage at home which allows me to control the PC, in the browser without activex. Thanks

UPDATE2: Is there perhaps any Java software I can run to host the remote session?

Comment: You should be able to use the Remote Desktop client built into Windows.  Otherwise there is always services like GoToMyPC which uses a browser plug-in.

Comment: does it have to be RDP or would other protocols work?

Comment: Since you mentioned Java, is properJavaRDP an option? It could also be run as an applet in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**No**"

I haven't been able to find any mechanism to connect in the way I describe in my question.

Thank you to others who have given suggestions

Answer (score 0):

With regards to accessing RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol), I doubt you would be able to do that on Firefox. I guess the only thing I can advise you with is LogMeIn. I'm actually using it on a constant basis and it's free if you're only after the remote controlling feature. As far as I know, it works on Firefox, Google Chrome and other modern web browsers.

Comment: but unfortunately, their page is blocked by my proxy :)

Answer (score 0):

"Yes" And there's quite a few ways to do this.

Many VNC clients come with a java client - for example realvnc and ultravnc - these run a mini web server which you can access vnc over.

If you have a little more time and patience, there's also a html5 client for vnc, though i've not really tried it on windows yet - its called [kanaka novnc](http://kanaka.github.com/noVNC/)

Now, if we could dump the firefox requirement, [chrome has a great plugin for remote access](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp)